# How to get only numbers at the beginning and end of a character in string with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
Example String : "as8d79asf5.dfdg dg s dgd2011/25klsdsj jdıo84823 jhgfkasfsf 2001/26llkasdjfıo";
```

I want to get only number from string.

Result:

1. 2011/25
2. 2001/26

EDIT:

The number of characters is not clear in string. For Example : 2/1234 , 214/1 , 22/2545 . May be all.

How do I get this result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
\d+/\d+
```

Otherwise if you exactly look for a 4digit/2digit:

```
\d{4}/\d{2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using only `@"\d+/\d+"` would be enough

Answer (score 1):

You could use an expression like (C# quoted):

```
@"\d{4}/\d\d"
```

Altho that has nothing to do with "beginning and end of character".

Comment: it works. But The number of characters is not clear in string. For Example : 2/1234 , 214/1 , 22/2545 . May be all.

Comment: @sin, not possible to tell from your question. Anyway, in that case use the expression `\d+/\d+` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
string input="as8d79asf5.dfdg dg s dgd2011/25klsdsj jdıo84823 jhgfkasfsf 2001/26llkasdjfıo";
        Regex nmRegex = new Regex(@"([\d]+/[\d]+)");
        var matches = nmRegex.Matches(input);
        List<string> matchedStrings = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            var g = matches[i].Groups;
            if (g.Count > 0)
                matchedStrings.Add(g[1].Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this regular expression maybe?

```
([[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2})
```

Not solid in C# though.